# Formatting csv files and/or dataframe columns from converted RINEX files

Tags: python, csv, gps, dataframe

Formatting csv files and/or dataframe columns from converted RINEX files

I'm trying to format a dataframe before being written to a csv file. The first issue I have is to strip the output from a RINEX file's dates/times, so that just the time is given:

```
    L1  L2  P1  P2  C1  S1  S2
2014-04-27 00:00:00                         
2014-04-27 00:00:30
```

In addition, the above column headings (these represent basically signals on satellites) are to be aligned. The below output in my csv file is also to be formatted so that the columns are for example right justified and therefore straight.

```
2014-04-27 05:01:30 -993864.147 -769167.945 23638879.454    23638880.731    23638879.193    47.0    42.0
2014-04-27 05:02:00 -1093051.608    -846456.845 23620004.727    23620005.748    23620003.334    47.0    42.0
2014-04-27 05:02:30 -1192060.664    -923606.729 23601163.403    23601164.435    23601163.315    47.0    42.0
2014-04-27 05:03:00 -1290882.849    -1000611.009    23582358.959    23582360.179    23582359.429    47.0    42.0
2014-04-27 05:03:30 -1389517.149    -1077468.879    23563589.575    23563590.085    23563590.032    47.0    42.0
2014-04-27 05:04:00 -1487961.416    -1154178.674    23544856.908    23544857.096    23544856.147    46.0    42.0
```

The code I have used so far:

def read_data(self, RINEXfile):
        obs_data_chunks = []

```
    while True:
        obss, _, _, epochs, _ = self.read_data_chunk(RINEXfile)

        if obss.shape[0] == 0:
            break

        obs_data_chunks.append(pd.Panel(
            np.rollaxis(obss, 1, 0),
            items=['G%02d' % d for d in range(1, 33)],
            major_axis=epochs,
            minor_axis=self.obs_types
        ).dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=2, how='all'))

        obs_data_chunks_dataframe = obs_data_chunks[0]

        for sv in range(32):
            sat = obs_data_chunks_dataframe[sv, :]
            #print "sv_data: {0}".format(sat)
            #sat[0] = sat[0].apply(pd.datetools.normalize_date)
            sat.to_csv(('sv_data_{0}').format(sv), sep='\t')
            #pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 2900)
```

The commented out code describes the kind of tactics I've used so far, and failed. Where can I improve my code to perform these tasks? Do I perform the formatting on the dataframe (i.e the "sat") or on the generated file (i.e. the "sv_data{0}")?

Comment: Do you want to output a delimited file or a fixed width one?  You speak of csv which is delimited but you also speak of alignment of fields as you would get with fixed width.  Which is it?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes I'd actually like to have the columns of fixed width and therefore aligned, but seperated by spaces. Thanks